# Laplace to gradient chain rule

Tags: vector-analysis, chain-rule, laplace-method

how do I do the chain rule for  f(-$\Delta$)gh if f,g,h are functions and I want it written in terms of gradients.

I know f(-$\Delta$)g= $\nabla$f x $\nabla$g.

Comment: I wish I could read your question because it looks like it might be engaging.  But alas, I cannot. Do you think you might format it in $\LaTeX$?  Using mathjax?  Cheers!

Comment: I tried and I couldn't figure out how to do it. Ill try again though

Comment: Got it @RobertLewis

Comment: OK, thanks.  But I'm still having a little trouble trying to understand what you mean by $f(-\Delta)g$ etc.  By the way did you know that $\Delta$ usually means $\nabla^2$, the Laplace operator, whereas $\nabla$ is used for gradient.  Can you take it a little further?  Cheers!